# SSRS 2008 R2 Header Row not exported to PDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a problem with the header row, this is not showing in the pages where the group continues with a large data in one of the fields. If the group ends and continue to the next page with new group it shows the headers but not when the group is cut and continue to the next page.

I found some post about the same issue but they are related to the previous version, we have SSRS 2008 R2 SP1. Someone knows if there is a hotfix for this issue?.

I have created a simple report to test and applied all the known settings like in the tablix properties check to repeat headers, also the rows and columns pane set properties to the static fields...

This problem appears in the print layout or when it is exported to pdf.

Any help please...

Thanks

Comment: check your report margin...

Comment: I think the margin is ok, since the report display well when the data of the records are not so large.